# Chart's y-axis line minimum value

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I am having a problem with chart properties. Before, there is an option to set the minimum value. I was able to set it but it suddenly changed and I can't find the option to set that again. Does anyone know how to change it from this:

[image]

into something like the image below?

[image]

Comment: can you show your xml with simple sample with just chart?

Comment: What version of Cognos?  Charting changed drastically in 10.x. If you're in 10.x, in Report Studio, go to `Tools > Advanced`, and see if `Use legacy chart authoring` is checked or cleared. I'm betting it's cleared.  Check it, add a chart, and see if you get the option you're looking for.

Comment: @Andrew, you can do it in 10x with the new charts, it's just harder to find the option. Took me a few clicks to find. You have to click on the Axis, not on the Axis Values. See http://therealtoddnappi.blogspot.com/2012/12/cognos-10-axis-range.html for pictures.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks but it did not work for me. I am using version 10.2.

Comment: the reason is **CY Actual** is under -%20 right?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar what do you mean under -20%? It doesn't have a value lower than -20.

Comment: do send the the view tabular data? because when I try it on cognos 10.2.1 I see the minumum value is %20

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar I edited again the question. I do have a negative value.

Comment: how can I import report from xml ?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar I don't know how to import a report.-__-

Answer (score 0):

Click on axis and set property "Axis Range"

Comment: I already set the minimum value. It worked before but suddenly it's not working. :( Do you have any idea why it stopped taking effect?

Comment: I presume you have values below -20%. Drop them or set to -20%
btw, what type of chart are you using?

Comment: I don't have a value lower than -20% but I noticed that whenever I remove the data item on x-axis it's working fine. But I need to have a value on x-axis.